Can we have two different distinct Search pages in Experience Cloud?
We have requirements to have two different distinct Search pages in Experience Cloud.
One page should use custom Coveo search while all other pages should use standard search.
I understand we can have two different themes for one page and override there global search box with custom Coveo search box on one theme but the search page will not be overridden for one page only

We created a separate Experience Cloud page which we called Coveo Search and placed Coveo search results there.
Then on global search box override we set Search Url attribute to the API-name of the new page, coveo-search and it worked.
